# How to normalize a Column of Dictionary Type in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas a dataframe which contains two columns. 1) keywords 2) TopicID.

The keyword is dictionary type. I want to normalize this dataframe in a way that each topic will repeat for each keyword and its value.

My Dataframe
[image: Source Dataframe]

**Expected Dataframe** (for sample I am posting few keywords only)

[image: Expcted]

I tried this code

```
df_final = pd.json_normalize(df.keywords.apply(json.loads))
```

Output of-> print (df[['TopicID','keywords']].head(2).to_dict())

```
{'TopicID': {0: 797, 1: 798}, 'keywords': {0: {'licence': 0.529, 'chapter': 0.462, 'explains': 0.263, 'visitor': 0.244, 'resident': 0.22, 'applying': 0.205, 'privileges': 0.199, 'graduated': 0.188, 'tests': 0.184, 'licensing': 0.18}, 1: {'emotional': 0.352, 'mental': 0.327, 'state': 0.309, 'operate': 0.295, 'drive': 0.242, 'motor': 0.227, 'ability': 0.227, 'next': 0.176, 'illness': 0.176, 'diminish': 0.176}}}
```

Comment: maybe some data related problem, what is `print (df.head(2).to_dict())` ?

Comment: {'TopicID': {0: 797, 1: 798}, 'keywords': {0: {'licence': 0.529, 'chapter': 0.462, 'explains': 0.263, 'visitor': 0.244, 'resident': 0.22, 'applying': 0.205, 'privileges': 0.199, 'graduated': 0.188, 'tests': 0.184, 'licensing': 0.18}, 1: {'emotional': 0.352, 'mental': 0.327, 'state': 0.309, 'operate': 0.295, 'drive': 0.242, 'motor': 0.227, 'ability': 0.227, 'next': 0.176, 'illness': 0.176, 'diminish': 0.176}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list of tuples by flatten dictonary in list comprehension first and then pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [(a, k, v) for a, b in zip(df['TopicID'], df['keywords']) for k, v in b.items()]
df_final = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['TopicID','Keyword','Value'])
print (df_final)
    TopicID     Keyword  Value
0       797     licence  0.529
1       797     chapter  0.462
2       797    explains  0.263
3       797     visitor  0.244
4       797    resident  0.220
5       797    applying  0.205
6       797  privileges  0.199
7       797   graduated  0.188
8       797       tests  0.184
9       797   licensing  0.180
10      798   emotional  0.352
11      798      mental  0.327
12      798       state  0.309
13      798     operate  0.295
14      798       drive  0.242
15      798       motor  0.227
16      798     ability  0.227
17      798        next  0.176
18      798     illness  0.176
19      798    diminish  0.176
```